# Is there a plugin that makes extnernal links open in new window, BUT

Tags: plugins, plugin-recommendation

Is there a plugin that makes external links open in new window, BUT only on the pages or domains or links I specify?

Comment: what's the point? if you want `target="_blank"` on specific links why not just add it manually?

Comment: yes dreamgrowers,if you got answer means just accept the answer and earn 2 points....:)

Comment: I have hundreds of outbound links which I would like to open in a new tab, but have exceptions be possible. I've seen plugins to make external links open in a new tab, but it's an all or nothing thing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Simple Popup Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-popup-plugin/screenshots/) . this plugin helps to made external links open..[WordPress Popup Scheduler](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-popup-scheduler/)

Comment: I have hundreds of outbound links which I would like to open in a new tab, but have exceptions be possible. I've seen plugins to make external links open in a new tab, but it's an all or nothing thing...

Answer (score 1):

It's not that hard - depending where you want it:

```
<?php
/* Plugin Name: (#21153) Open links in new window/tab */

function wpse21153_open_new_window( $content )
{
    // Add all your statements, when a link has to open in a new tab, here.
    if ( is_page() )
        return link_add_target( $content );

    return $content;
}
foreach( array( 'content', 'excerpt' ) as $location )
    add_action( "the_{$location}", 'wpse21153_open_new_window' );
```